ref.watch(myProvider) does not return
I having been using riverpod for a long time now. As is programing, some times you come across a problem i feel like WTF.
I have this basic line:
@riverpod
FutureOr<List<PlaceAutocomplete>> placeAutocompleteState(
  PlaceAutocompleteStateRef ref,
) {
  final repoProvider = ref.watch(mapRepoProvider);
  debugPrint("repoProvider: $repoProvider");
  final query = ref.watch(placeAutocompleteQueryProvider);
  debugPrint("my query: $query");
  return query.fold(
    () => const [],
    (query) => ref.watch(getPlaceAutocompleteProvider(query).future),
  );
}

The line debugPrint("repoProvider: $repoProvider"); is not printing, which means that ref.watch(mapRepoProvider) is not returning. I put that in there because I was wondering at some other part of the code why I was getting no result. If I remove ref.watch(mapRepoProvider) I can see the print of debugPrint("my query: $query");
mapRepoProvider is defined as follows:
part 'map_repo.g.dart';

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
MapRepo mapRepo(MapRepoRef ref) {
  return MapRepo(
    remoteDataSource: ref.watch(mapRemoteDataSourceProvider),
  );
}

class MapRepo {
  MapRepo({
    required this.remoteDataSource,
  });

  final MapRemoteDataSource remoteDataSource;

  Future<List<PlaceAutocomplete>> getPlaceAutocomplete(
      String placeName, {
        CancelToken? cancelToken,
      }) async {
    debugPrint("placeautocomplete");
    final autocomplete =
    await remoteDataSource.getPlaceAutocomplete(placeName, cancelToken: cancelToken);
    return autocomplete.map((item) => item.toDomain()).toList();
  }
}

ref.watch(otherProvider) works fine at other places with other providers. I cannot understand why this one specifically is blocking.

Do you get any errors?

Nope, I can't see any exception

I use Riverpod too, but don't use auto-generation so I don't even know how to read the above.  However, I do spot a FutureOr. Should that function not be marked as async?    Also, how is mapRemoteDataSourceProvider defined?

I had a Dio class which was defined as follows:
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
Dio googleMapDio(GoogleMapDioRef ref) {
  final logger = Logger('Dio')..level = Level.FINEST;
  final sub = logger.onRecord.listen((record) {
    debugPrint('${record.level.name}: ${record.time}: ${record.message}');
  });
  ref.onDispose(sub.cancel);
  return Dio()
    ..options = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: GoogleMapApiConfig.googleMapBaseUrl,
      connectTimeout: MainApiConfig.connectTimeout,
      receiveTimeout: MainApiConfig.receiveTimeout,
    )
    ..interceptors.addAll([
      //order is necessary.
      ContentTypeInterceptor(),
      ApiKeyInterceptor(),
      //ref.watch(sessionTokenInterceptorProvider),
      ErrorInterceptor(),
      LogInterceptor(logPrint: logger.finest),
    ]);
}

The logger was causing the problem but I don't know why. After removing it, it works

Maybe for some reason it throws an exception. You can add a provider observer and check what occurs in the debug console.
